# Xpath only find lowercase SQL-Keywords

Tags: xpath, sonarqube

I'm creating a SonarCube rule that checks all sql-files. This rule should check if all keywords like SELECT, INSERT etc are written in uppercase.

```
IF NOT EXISTS(select * FROM sys.columns Where Name = N'idUser' AND Object_ID = Object_ID(N'lp_t_Rpt_Order'))
ALTER TABLE lp_t_Rpt_Order
    ADD idUser INT NULL
```

In this case the xpath query should match 'select' and 'Where' which do not follow the rule of being all UPPERCASE.

I have a list of all keywords so I find them, but know I want to know how I have to write or expand the xpath expression to only match words containing lowercase letters.

```
/COMPILATION_UNIT//*[@tokenValue = 'SELECT' or @tokenValue = 'INSERT' or @tokenValue = 'WHERE']
```

This is a shortend version of my xpath expression. If I included all key words the query would be way to long to display on this site.

[image: This is the Abstract Syntax Tree]
This is how the Abstract Syntax Tree looks like.

Comment: Which versions of XPath are supported?  From v2 onwards there's an `upper-case(.)` function whilst in V1 you'd need to use `translate(.,'qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm','QWERTYUIOPSDFGHJKLZXCVBNM') to convert something to upper case.

Comment: There are multiple parts to your question; XPath naturally does case-sensitive comparisons, so simply compare a value with the upper case version of the same value; if they don't match it's not entirely upper case.

Comment: The harder part would be finding the keywords / parsing the syntax (i.e. so `SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE something = 'select'` doesn't check the second `select` and error on this value.  Maybe SonarQube handles that bit for you; sadly I'm unfamiliar with that tech so can't help there.